# How to count average number of comparisons in optimised Bozosort

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, combinatorics

A bozosort is a slow sorting algorithm: two elements in the array are picked uniformly at random and swapped if they make an inversion(n if i < j and a[i] > a[j]). We must find an average number of comparisons needed to sort a given array of numbers from 1 to 10 which do not repeat.
For instance,  for 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 number of swaps is 0
for 2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 number of swaps is (10,2)=45
I thought it was simple: count number of inversions and multiply by C(10,2). But after running tests I saw my solution was incorrect

```
 double sort(vector<int>& a) { 
        double count = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; i++)
          for (int j = i + 1; j < a.size(); j++)
          if (a[i] > a[j]) count++; 
      return count;
      }
double val = 45.000000;
 cout  << val * sort(vect) << endl;
```

Comment: That is you task, but what is your question and how is this related to C++?

Comment: The code must be written in c++. We are given an array of integers from1 to 10 and must find an average number of swaps in order to sort it via optimised bozosort

Comment: Well, then you know what to do. What is your question?  Where did you get stuck and how may we help you?

Comment: I thought that the solution was simple: count number of inversions in the array and multiply it by C(10,2). But when I tried running tests, only 4 out of 10 were correct

Comment: "for 2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 number of swaps is (10,2)=45". I don't understand this; shouldn't the number of swaps for this example be exactly 1? The only possible swap is i=0,j=1, and then the list is sorted.

Comment: Shouldn't the _average_ number of swaps for Bozosort (that's another name for Bogosort, right?) be the number of possible permutations of the input? So `N!`?

Comment: We choose elements randomly, so in order to run through all 10 elements and detect the ones which are not on corrects position we must choose  45 random pairs of elements

Comment: So you are not interested in the number of swaps, but the number of comparisons?

Comment: It looks like the number of swaps depends on the array, because the answer is different for different test cases

Comment: The text in your question is not like you comment here. You write *"2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 number of swaps is (10,2)=45"*. That just is not true. If for instance it randomly chooses 5 and 7, it will compare them and decide that it should *not* swap.

Comment: I meant number of comparisons. Sorry for misleading

Comment: "Average number of swaps" means *average* number of swaps. I don't see you calculating an average of anything. Hint: you should average over *all possible arrays*. There are 10! or 3628800 of them. And also average over all possible random swap sequences. For example, you can sort `{10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1}` in one swap, or in 17, or anything in between.

Comment: On the other hand, the average number of comparisons is infinite, because the algorithm doesn't ever terminate.

Comment: The question still mentions number of swaps. You should update the question to reflect the comments.

Comment: This seems like the optimized Bozosort. @churill that's different from Bogosort. (Bogosort repeatedly permutes the array and checks if sorted, Unoptimized Bozosort repeatedly transposes elements and checks if sorted.)